# HQL to Criteria Conversion Issues

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have some issues with converting a HQL to a Criteria query. As part of the specification, I need the return value of the Criteria query to be of type Criteria, this may not be changed.

This is my fully working HQL query:

```
select sum(m.frequent / case when m.vigilants.size > 1 then m.vigilants.size 
else 1 end) from Museum m inner join m.vigilants v where size(m.vigilants) > 1 
and v.forename = 'Mike Jones' or size(m.vigilants) = 1 and v.forename='Mike Jones'
```

And this is my attempt so far at getting a Criteria Query

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Museum.class, "m");
criteria.createAlias("m.vigilants", "v"); 
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("m.id")));
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.sizeGt("vigilants", 1), Restrictions.eq("v.forename", "Mike Jones")));
```

I honestly am really stuck and have been trying for a day to get this to work, and I don't know how I can get this HQL converted to a Criteria query!

Answer (score 0):

I usually have to fiddle with these things for a while before I get the completely correct but here is a first pass for you to start with.

Also, the whole `size > 1 or size == 1` thing boils down to `size >= 1` which is implicit if you're doing an inner join so I just left it out.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Number> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Museum> root = query.from(Museum.class);
Join<Museum, Vigilant> vigilantsJoin = root.join("vigilants");
Predicate forenameIsMikeJones = builder.equal(vigilantsJoin.get("forename"), "Mike Joines");
Expression<Integer> numVigilants= builder.size(root.get("vigilants"));
Expression<Number> freqOverNumVigilants = builder.quot(root.get("frequent"), numVigilants);
Expression<Sum> sumOfFreqOverNumVigilants = builder.sum(freqOverNumVigilants);
query.select(sumOfFreqOverNumVigilants).where(forenameIsMikeJones);
TypedQuery<Number> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
```